# SQL Server recursive function getting middle data tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have example data in the table as follows:

```
id,  name , parentid
--------------------
1 , jason , null
2 , john  , 1
3 , abe   , 2
4 , mary  , 2
5 , yong  , 4
6 , albert, 5 
7 , jane  , 3
8 , alex  , 7
```

How do I get the middle part of the tree data if I only want 2 levels from the selected `parentid` example `john,abe,mary,jane` in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: YOU SAID YOU WANT 2 LEVEL FROM SELECTED PARENT. For parent 1 - two level nodes are 2,3,4,5,6 But In your question you mention john,abe,mary,jane then where is yong(5). If i am wrong. Explain with example.

Comment: oh yeah thanks forgot the yong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this query: just selected the Childs of current parent and child's childs.

```
DECLARE @SelectedID INT
SET @SelectedID = 1

SELECT ID, NAME, PARENTID  FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID = @SelectedID
UNION ALL
SELECT  ID, NAME, PARENTID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID IN
    (SELECT ID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID = @SelectedID)
UNION ALL
SELECT  ID, NAME, PARENTID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID IN
    (SELECT ID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID IN
        (SELECT ID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID = @SelectedID))
```

I have created a stored proc to achieve get childs based on used input.

Just Run the SP (Before that change the table name #Table1 to your table name)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetChilds(@SelectedID INT, @SelectedLevel INT)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentLevel INT 
    SET @CurrentLevel = 0

    CREATE TABLE #TABLENew(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), PARENTID INT, Level INT) 
    CREATE TABLE #TABLETemp1(ID INT)
    CREATE TABLE #TABLETemp2(ID INT)

    INSERT INTO #TABLETemp1(ID) 
          SELECT ID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID = @SelectedID

     INSERT INTO #TABLENew (ID, NAME, PARENTID, Level) 
            SELECT ID, NAME, PARENTID, @CurrentLevel FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID IN(@SelectedID)

    SET @CurrentLevel = @CurrentLevel + 1

    INSERT INTO #TABLETemp2(ID) 
          SELECT ID FROM #TABLETemp1

    WHILE (@CurrentLevel <= @SelectedLevel)
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO #TABLENew (ID, NAME, PARENTID, Level) 
            SELECT ID, NAME, PARENTID, @CurrentLevel FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID IN(SELECT ID FROM #TABLETemp1)

     TRUNCATE TABLE #TABLETemp1

     INSERT INTO #TABLETemp1(ID) 
          SELECT ID FROM #TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID IN(SELECT ID FROM #TABLETemp2)

     TRUNCATE TABLE #TABLETemp2

      INSERT INTO #TABLETemp2(ID) 
          SELECT ID FROM #TABLETemp1

     SET @CurrentLevel = @CurrentLevel + 1
    END

    SELECT * FROM #TABLENew
    DROP TABLE #TABLENew
    DROP TABLE #TABLETemp1
    DROP TABLE #TABLETemp2
END
```

To execute the result.(1 - Parent, 2 - Level)

```
EXEC GetChilds 1, 2
```

Comment: hi yes this is what i am looking for but is it possible to provide the code for dynamic level example if i allow the user to select 1 or 2 or 4 level

Comment: Ya, I know what you want. Just wait a moment. I am working on it.

Comment: check out the answer. and Update what you get.

Comment: omg you are a life saviour that is 100% what i wanted, if you were right beside me now i would have bought you a drink

Comment: click on the tick mark on the left side of my answer. below down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need:

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
SELECT ID,Name,parentID, 1 Depth  FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  E.ID,E.Name,E.ParentID,Depth+1 Depth  FROM YourTable E
INNER JOIN CTE ON E.ParentID=CTE.ID)

SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE Depth = 2
```

NOTE that the where clause in the second select gets the depth, and the answer assumes that you are looking for the second level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
declare @parentID int;
declare @level int;
set @parentID = 1;
set @level = 2;
select name FROM TestTable123414 where parentid between @parentID and @parentID+@level
```

**Output**

```
john
abe
mary
jane
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test table(id int, name varchar(50), parentid int)

insert into @test values
( 1,'jason' , null ),
( 2,'john' , 1),
( 3,'abe' , 2),
( 4,'mary' , 2),
( 5,'yong' , 4),
( 6,'albert' , 3),
( 7,'jane' , 3),
( 8,'alex' , 7)


declare @level int, @currentid int;
set @level = 2;
set @currentid = 1

select * from @test where parentid in (
select id from @test where id between @currentid and @currentid+@level )
```